# Application displays a revolving Windows Logo on Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I have created an application for quite old Windows Mobile 5 based handhelds using VS 2008, c# and .net core 2.0. Here is the, erm, code, which I use to show the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace TestEmptyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        while (true) { };  // ended by the debugger or device boot
        }
    }
}
```

I choose the "Smart Device Project" "Console Application" boilerplate. If I run it, a revolving image resembling the Windows logo (4 coloured patches, red, green, yellow, blue) appears on the display. I need the application to run entirely silent.

How can I get rid of the logo?

Comment: As Windows Mobile 5/6 does not really have a console, creating a console project makes no sense. Very erratic, that VS 2008 offers such a template. You better start with a forms project and hide the main form after start. Or you go with C/C++ and create a console project, this will start hidden and run until you stop that from code or kill the process. I have done a lot of 'services' and background apps using C/C++ on WM6. In cotrast to that, Windows CE 5/6/7 ... have a console, and there a C# Console project makes sense. You need to install the WinCE platform SDK for the device OS.

Comment: Confused. What does the Language (c/c++ vs. c#) have to do with whether a revolving logo appears or not? I mean console is console, no matter which language you choose. If Mobile doesn't have a console at all, why then should it have one for c/c++?

Comment: Nevertheless I'll give the hidden GUI approach a try,

Comment: Windows Mobile 5/6 does not have a console! DotNet framework does many weird things in the background. Using C/C++ is more native and direct. You can write a cnsole app but without a standard input and output. Good for running background tasks. See, for example, https://github.com/hjgode/win-mobile-code/tree/master/TimeZoneSet